# Как добавить анимацию при нажатии кнопки назад в fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation

Есть `Fragment` в нём кнопка, по нажатию открывается с анимацией следующий `Fragment`, но по нажатию кнопки назад то есть `onbackpressed` возвращается предыдущий `Fragment` но без анимации. Как добавить анимацию по нажатию на `onbackpressed`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Fragment` из которого переходим

```
public class FragmentAttraction extends Fragment {

    FragmentGyro fragmentGyro;
    BlankFragment blankFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentGyro = new FragmentGyro();
        blankFragment= new BlankFragment();

        CardView gyro_loop = requireView().findViewById(R.id.Gyro_Loop_);


        gyro_loop.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.transition_enter, R.anim.transition_exit);
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment, blankFragment, "detailFragment");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.transition_enter, R.anim.transition_exit, R.anim.transition_enter, R.anim.transition_exit);`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - использовать другую встроенную анимацию. Например так:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,
                R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421701/how-to-apply-a-fade-in-fade-out-animation-when-replacing-a-fragment). И вот так же советую ознакомится с [документацией](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate) по анимированию переходов, там много интересного есть.

Comment: Вся проблема чтобы анимация работала при нажатии на `onbackpressed`, как назначить на `button` я знаю.